# Перескакивает бордер при скролле до нужного блока

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Народ, есть ли какой-то плагин или что-нибудь готовое, чтоб реализовать такое? Шапка фиксированная, и нижний бордер перескакивает на разделы, до которых скроллит пользователь.

Comment: Берешь <hr /> вставляешь в div и изощряешься как душа пожелает

Comment: Никогда не понимал почему для всяких тривиальных задач люди всегда ищут грамоздкие библиотеки, которые могут значительно повлиять на размер сборки. Гуглите `clientHeight`, `scrollTop`, `getBoundingRect`, ну и псевдоэлементы. Больше ничего не понадобится.

Comment: @MishaSaidov наверное потому-что люди программирование не знают.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не сложное решение на jQuery

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $(".div a").each(function() {
    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var div_1 = $(this).attr('href');
    var div_top = $(div_1).offset().top;

    if (window_top > div_top - 100) {
      $('.div').find('a').removeClass('active');
      $('.div').find('a[href="' + div_1 + '"]').addClass('active');
    } else {
      $('.div').find('a[href="' + div_1 + '"]').removeClass('active');
    };
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.div {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background: #fff;
}

.div a {
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.item {
  height: 100%;
}

.active {
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <a href="#div1">1</a>
  <a href="#div2">2</a>
  <a href="#div3">3</a>
</div>

<div id="div1" class="item">первый блок</div>
<div id="div2" class="item">второй блок</div>
<div id="div3" class="item">третий блок</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```